# Libgdx box2d bodies go through other bodies

Tags: 2d, android, libgdx, box2d

I'm  developing a game using libGDX and box2d. I am facing a problem that bodies go through each other... I'm moving the body using a TouchPad by setTransform. I think the problem is that I use setTransform.

Comment: You need to give us more details than that, as it stands the question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use forces and impulses (physics) and the bodies will collide properly.
I suggest you to do this like this:

```
body.applyForceToCenter(force.x*pad.getKnobPercentX(),force.y*pad.getKnobPercentY());
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, so I'm posting this as an answer. You should've provided some code. I had a similar issue, I was moving box2d bodies with `.setTransform`. When using box2d, it's recommended that you move bodies applying forces. I don't know if that's your problem, so you might want to check how you're moving the bodies in your game. This can be due to several other problems, I can't tell without any code. I'm just sharing a similar issue that I had.